# Why do I get an error when passing input value into function parameter but not when statically assigning it?

Tags: python, string, function, class, parameter-passing

When I manually type "alex" into the "printPeople" parameter, the code prints out fine.

```
class people:  
    name = ''
    age = ''

alex = people()
alex.name = 'Alex'
alex.age = '25'

clarance = people()
clarance.name = 'Clarance'
clarance.age = '24'

def printPeople(person):
    print('-' * 20)
    print('Name:', person.name)
    print('Age:', person.age)
    print('-' * 20)

printPeople(alex)
```

However, if I try using an input function to manually choose a name:

```
class people:  
name = ''
age = ''

alex = people()
alex.name = 'Alex'
alex.age = '25'

clarance = people()
clarance.name = 'Clarance'
clarance.age = '24'

def printPeople(person):
    print('-' * 20)
    print('Name:', person.name)
    print('Age:', person.age)
    print('-' * 20)

userInput = input('Enter name: ')
printPeople(userInput)
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: `alex` is a variable name, not a `str` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alex` is a variable

```
printPeople(alex)
```

not a `str` value like `input` returns

```
# Wrong
printPeople("alex")
```

If you want the input to select data in your program, use a `dict` which you can index with the user input.

```
people_data = {"alex": alex}

...

printPeople(people_data[userInput])
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy to understand workaround. Would there happen to be an ever simpler way to convert the string from 'input' into a function parameter?

Comment: I'm going to tell a white lie and say "No." (By which I mean, I'm *not* going to explain how to use `eval` to unsafely work around the issue.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, the simplest way to convert a string into a working function parameter. I've looked into it, and I get why it is unsafe to use. Does this mean that ANY time a user can run an expression, even to a single, specific function, this is a security risk? Or let me reframe; is there ANY function one could make with an eval() where no matter what a user typed, "import os delete files", it could be contained and and considered safe to use?

Comment: It depends on the function. But using `eval` presents the *opportunity* for something unintended to be executed, whereas the approach in this answer avoids that. It leaves the code itself in control of what gets executed.

Comment: Put another way: `eval` may be *syntactically* simpler, but it is *semantically* much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printPeople` function is expecting a `people` value, or at least some value with `name` and `age` attributes. When you call `printPeople(input())` you're passing a string into `printPeople`. That string does not have the required attributes.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a String Object and it has not an atrribute name.
You must know that in python everything is object.

In this two lines you are trying to access attributes name and age of the instance, hence you have an error.
print('Name:', person.name)
print('Age:', person.age)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).